# JLabel.setVisible(false) will not work until end of ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, button, awt, actionlistener

I am just trying to get a loadingbar.gif to load into the frame when the Accept button is clicked. And it will not add to the frame until after the ActionListener gets to the end, which defeats the entire purpose of showing a loading bar. I tried adding .repaint() but that will not work.

acceptButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            lbl.setVisible(true);
            lbl.repaint();

            try
            {............
```

This is the bit if code im talking about. It just does it once the ActionListener completes everything after it.

```
public class PrintSheet extends JDialog {

private JPanel contentPane;

private  MainFrame mainGui;

private DbWorker db;
private Connection con;
private JLabel lbl;

public PrintSheet(final MainFrame mainGui) {
    setResizable(false);

    this.mainGui = mainGui;

    setAlwaysOnTop(true);

    setBounds(100, 100, 180, 125);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    URL url = getClass().getResource("/images/loading_bar_small.gif");
    Icon img = new ImageIcon(url);
    lbl = new JLabel(img);
    lbl.setBounds(0, 70, 164, 17);

    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    lbl.setVisible(false);
    getContentPane().add(lbl);

    JLabel lblPrintSignSheet = new JLabel("Print Sign-In Sheet: ");
    lblPrintSignSheet.setBounds(10, 11, 128, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblPrintSignSheet);

    JButton acceptButton = new JButton("Accept");
    acceptButton.setBounds(10, 36, 65, 23);

    acceptButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            lbl.setVisible(true);
            lbl.repaint();

            try
            {
                db = new DbWorker(DatabaseStore.getAddress(), DatabaseStore.getPort(),
                        DatabaseStore.getUserName(), DatabaseStore.getPassword());
                con = db.getConnection();

            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                new DbConnectErrorDialog().setVisible(true);
            }


            String OUT_PUT = "./sign_in_sheet.xlsx";

            String REPORT = "/certificates/Signing_List.jrxml";

            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            //map.put("FirstName",firstName);

            try
            {
                JasperDesign jd  = JRXmlLoader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(REPORT));
                JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
                JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, map, con);
                JRXlsxExporter export = new JRXlsxExporter();
                export.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jp));
                export.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(new File(OUT_PUT)));
                SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration config = new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration();
                export.setConfiguration(config);
                export.exportReport();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainGui, "<html>The sign-in sheet was successfully created</html>");

                lbl.setVisible(false);
                setVisible(false);
                lbl.repaint();

                //Opens file after completed export
                OpenFile(OUT_PUT);
            } catch (JRException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                lbl.setVisible(false);
                lbl.repaint();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainGui, "<html>The sign-in sheet could not be created due to an error:<br>" + ex + "</html>", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }


        }
    });
    contentPane.add(acceptButton);

    JButton button = new JButton("Cancel");
    button.setBounds(85, 36, 79, 23);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(button);


}

public void OpenFile(String path)
{
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        try {
            File myFile = new File(path);
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // no application registered for PDFs
        }
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `revalidate`, but that relates the layout management API, which you seem to have decided you don't need and can do a better job of, so not surprised you're having issues

Comment: well i was using a FlowLayout, but it wasnt working that way, so i changed it up to Absoulute, but still didnt do anything

Comment: You could use a more flexible layout manager, like `GridBagLayout`, then you would simply call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container which contains the label

Comment: You should never try to do anything in an ActionListener that will take more than a few milliseconds, since you will be blocking the event thread - no repaints will take place until your actionListener returns.

Comment: Okay, so can i just move the Large amount of code i want to preform to another method? Or how else would i perform the task?

Comment: @webminer07 Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and 
[Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)